# Difference in Time for "Date/Time Opened" field

Tags: deployment

I created a case which shows Date/Time Opened field value as "25/3/2015 4:57 PM" after the creation. But when i retrieve its value through query, it shows as "2015-03-25T11:27:29.000+0000" . Why is this time difference ?? What might be the reason for this issue ?? Anyone please clarify me .

Thanks in advance ..!!!

Answer (score 2):

The value returned through the query is in UTC. I'm guessing you have your user settings to a timezone 5.5hrs ahead of UTC (India).